# UIWebview Html5 with inline SVG

Tags: iphone, ios, html, uiwebview, svg

I am trying to draw a basic circle with SVG inside of an Html 5 file and then load that inside of a UIWebview. However when I compile and run nothing appears on screen (testing on iPad).

Am I not using the correct code or is SVG with Html 5 not supported in UIWebview?

Here is the code for the UIWebview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString*  path    = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SVG" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString*  content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    webView = [UIWebView new];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];
}
```

Here is the code inside the SVG.html file that is called in the resources folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>SVG</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<svg id="svgelem" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="redcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been reading through many related posts but I have not been able to puzzle out the answer.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Safari (or what's inside UIWebView) has problems with embedded SVG elements. I heard that Apple is going to fix it, anyway... 
Try this:

svg.html :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>SVG</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <object data="circle.svg" width="250" height="250"
    type="image/svg+xml" /> 
  </body>
</html>
```

circle.svg :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Hopefully I don't have to wait too long for Apple to fix the issue. But I am grateful for the work around anyway. Thank you! You get the big green tick :)

Comment: This is probably another post but do you know how to manipulate the SVG from the html file? For example change the fill color to green. I know how to do this inside the SVG file but I would prefer to do this in the html file. If you like I can start another post so you can earn another tick I just thought I'd ask first. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, don't bother about ticks :) I made some research and it seems that Safari doesn't have problems with inline SVG tags within xml files. Please look at the http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31624902/test.xml for reference. Ask me if you need any help.

Comment: Hmmm I couldn't get it to work. Only the button shows up not the triangle. I changed the extention to .xml as well. Thanks for looking into it for me though. Am I ment to execute it the same way as I have done above?

Comment: Glad if it helps. In this test website you have JavaScript changeColor function and you can call it directly in xml file, or inside your application with:    [ yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"changeColor();"];